# creating war file using jenkins and deploying it on server

Tags: maven, jenkins

I am facing a problem in my application. I want to create a war file for my maven application using jenkins and afterwords i want to deploy it on server. In the application I have two pom.xml file. So the question is how to generate war file for the application using jenkins?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IsH3F.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ruw9S.png)

so in this case I am getting an exception after building the application
[enter image description here][3]

and its showing build is failure

So what to do now? please suggest...

Comment: Please show your pom file...

Comment: I think, you are not aware how to build Java applications. Take the help of the Dev team to fix this, I hope Dev team can help you definitely its their day to day job.

Comment: Went through the screenshots, in POM text box provide full path along with pom.xml

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, check whether the `<packaging>war</packaging>` element is defined in your `pom.xml`.

Secondly, the path to POM in your `Invoke top-level Maven targets` seems to be incorrect, define the path including the pom.xml itself.

Thirdly, please, attach the build log stack with the error so we can consider the issue more precisely.